# InvalidPrintCommand error when calling SalReportPrint() function

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

The application was written in TD 6.2 version. When trying to print using builtin function SalReportPrint()-InavlidPrintCommand error has been received. I have already tried *Menu Report->Format->Report* option( qrp file) and  selected the check box *use defult printer* option but still getting same error.[image]

Answer (score 2):

had this case several times, using an older version of TD (4.1).
There my problem was that either the printer which it reported that it should be printing on was not installed or it wasn't set as a default printer.

Try to set your printer of choice to be default printer, using `SalPrtSetDefault()` before you do the printing action.